# How to join two table with CAST in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

I have two tables and I want to create a view to join them.

[image]

I created a picture to explain my problem. As you can see in picture above, values in table 1 are unique and I want to know that if a value in table 1 exists in table 2 or not. I would like to add a column that contain "NO" If it doesn't exist, if it does additional column must contain "YES".

I hope I could explain myself.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 2):

I would do this as:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.col = t1.col)
             then 'YES'
             else 'NO'
        end) as flag
from table1 t1;
```

This should be the most efficient way to accomplish this goal.  For best performance you want an index on `table2(col)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can left join the table2 with table1 and see if any rows exists.

```
select t1.col, case when count(t2.col) = 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.col = t2.col
group t1.col;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with A as
(select v from (values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e')) v(v))
, B as
(select v from (values ('a'),('a'),('b'),('b'),('b'),('c'),('c'),('d')) v(v))
-- This is where the magic happens
select
distinct a.v,case when b.v is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end existsinb
from  A
left join B
on a.v=b.v
order by v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check both sides with `full join`:

```
create view dbo.MyViewOfMissingValues
as
select 
    isnull(t1.col, t2.col) col, 
    case 
        when t2.col is null then 'No (missing in t2)' 
        when t1.col is null then 'No (missing in t1)' 
        else 'Yes' -- contained in both tables
    end col_status
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2
    on t1.col = t2.col
group isnull(t1.col, t2.col);
```